# loss of serpentine belt while running

Tags: serpentine-belt

I have a 2015 Civic LX.  Recently the serpentine belt broke while driving.  The engine started making an odd noise.  After about 5 minutes the engine stopped running with the smell of something burning.  The belt is replaced now and car is running.  But it makes that same noise with the application of power at low rpm, such as starting from a stop. No noise at higher rpm once the car is rolling.
Questions:
1) Why did the engine quit when the serpentine belt broke.  Afaik it was still getting air, fuel and spark.  So why did it stop?
2) What equipment may be damaged as a result of driving without a serpentine belt?
3) Any idea what the odd noise is at low rpm when you press the pedal a bit?

Comment: Is it really a fan belt?  Won’t the fan be electrically driven on that car?

Comment: @TimNevins - The serpentine belt doesn't turn the camshaft on any Honda I've ever worked on (or any other type of car I've ever worked on, for that matter). There is a cog belt (timing belt) which does that job, as well as run the water pump (in most models with Overhead Cam(s)).  Maybe you misspoke?

Answer (score 2):

1. Most likely alternator voltage drop could have cut the engine.
2. None of your equipment should be damaged with a loss of an accessory serpentine belt.
3. The odd noise could be a bad pulley or tensioner if it wasn't replaced with the belt. That can add odd noises before/after engine load.